# Whitelist statement from being logged by PostgreSQL due to log_min_duration_statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have configured my PostgreSQL 9.4 install to log statements that take over 500 ms using log_min_duration_statement

Now, I have a query that is expected to take in the order of 2 seconds. So it gets recorded every time is run.

I would like to whitelist this query so it doesn't show up in the logs or, even better, to configure log_min_duration_statement to only log that query is it takes over 5000 ms without affecting the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do that, but there are some workarounds.  You can set `log_min_duration_statement` from your client code before you run that one query.  Or you could run that query under a different user and have that user configured differently.

Comment: You might also find the `pg_stat_statements` extension interesting.